# error message: error: no match for call to '(cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM>) (cv::Mat&)'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm still new to `OpenCV 3.3` and `Qt` and I have a problem with my code. I've build anpr project for my thesis and applied some anpr code. Unfortunately I got an error which I can't solve.

```
void MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    DetectRegions detectRegions;
    detectRegions.saveRegions = false;
    detectRegions.showSteps = false;
    vector<plate> posible_regions = detectRegions.run(input_image);
    FileStorage fs;
    fs.open("SVM.xml", FileStorage::READ);
    Mat trainingDataMat;
    Mat Classes;
    fs["TrainingData"] >> trainingDataMat;
    fs["classes"] >> Classes;
    Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
    svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
    svm->setGamma(1);
    svm->setDegree(0);
    svm->setCoef0(0);
    svm->setC(1);
    svm->setNu(0);
    svm->setP(0);
    svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 1000, 0.01));
    Ptr<SVM> svmClassifier = (trainingDataMat, Classes, Mat(), Mat(), svm);

    vector<plate> Plates;
    for (int i = 0; i < posible_regions.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat img = posible_regions[i].plateImg;
        Mat p = img.reshape(1, 1);
        p.convertTo(p, CV_32FC1);
        int response = svmClassifier(p);  // produces error
        if (response == 1)
        {
            Plates.push_back(posible_regions[i]);
        }
    }

    ocr Ocr("OCR.xml");
    Ocr.saveSegments = false;
    Ocr.DEBUG = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Plates.size(); i++)
    {
        plate Plate = Plates[i];
        string plateNumber = Ocr.run(&Plate);
        string licensePlate = Plate.str();
        QString qstr2 = QString::fromStdString(licensePlate);
        ui->resultLineEdit->setText(qstr2);
    }
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
error: no match for call to '(cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM>) (cv::Mat&)' int response = svmClassifier(p);
```

Comment: `svmClassifier` is not a function but a pointer to the `SVM` object type. Maybe you wanted to call a function from that object like this `svmClassifier->function(p)`? Also, is this line a typo: `Ptr<SVM> svmClassifier = (trainingDataMat, Classes, Mat(), Mat(), svm);` Are you creating a `new SVM`?